# Display output from nested complex queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query as described below:

```
SELECT ID, TYPE || TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(INC_SLOT, 'INCR_', '')) AS INCR_SLOT, FEE
FROM
(
 SELECT * FROM RBDATA WHERE DEPT='HR';
)
UNPIVOT (FEE FOR INC_SLOT IN (INCR_1, INCR_2, INCR_3, INCR_4, INCR_5))
```

The structure of **RBDAT** table is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | DEPT | CAT | FNAME | LNAME | TYPE | INCR_1 | INCR_2 | INCR_3 | INCR_4 | INCR_5 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have another table called **PRIMS**, which is structured as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | DEPT | CAT | FNAME | LNAME | DOB | SEX | STATUS | SEC |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to display the ID, SEC, INCR_SLOT, FEE, when the ID, DEPT, and CAT match up for values present within the PRIMS and RBDATA.

Thank you so much for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For less complication, I would do another SELECT:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.SEC, A.INCR_SLOT, A.FEE
 FROM(
        SELECT ID, TYPE || TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(INC_SLOT, 'INCR_', '')) AS INCR_SLOT
            --ADDING THIS TOO
               , DEPT, CAT
            --
            , FEE
          FROM
            (
             SELECT * FROM RBDATA WHERE DEPT='HR';
            )
        UNPIVOT (FEE FOR INC_SLOT IN (INCR_1, INCR_2, INCR_3, INCR_4, INCR_5))
  ) A,
  PRIMS B
 WHERE A.ID = B.ID
   AND A.DEPT = B.DEPT
   AND A.CAT = B.CAT;
```

Comment: when I try to add the following clause AND A.FEE IS NULL to the existing clauses, I don't see anything display, although I have plenty of rows with FEE = NULL. Thanks again in advance!

Comment: @Shib Try with "..UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS ( FEE FOR INC_SLOT..."

Comment: Thanks @Fernando Gonzalez this helped!